# Java Error based around java.lang.NumberFormatException concerning some sort of "infinite" value

Tags: java, arraylist, double, java.lang.class

I am working on a program which evaluates a given string as a mathematical function at a given x value.  I am currently experiencing an error listed as such:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-Infinity3"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at function.operateMD(function.java:212)
at function.evaluate(function.java:39)
at Graph.draw(Graph.java:127)
at Graph.main(Graph.java:22)
```

I am unsure why I am recieving this error.  The string sent to the method is `"3x-1"`

My code essentially takes the String, breaks it into strings of one index, judges what value each of those would be mathematically (i.e. operator, variable, etc.) and runs a series of methods to simplify the function and then evaluate it at a given x value. The method in at which the error occurs (function.operateMD) is here:

```
public static void operateMD()
{
    double tempPROD=0;
    double tempP1=0;
    double tempP2=0;

    for(int h=0;h<parts.size();h++)
    {
        if(types.get(h).equals("opr"))
        {
            tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h-1));
            tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
            if(parts.get(h).equals("*"))
            {
                tempPROD=tempP1*tempP2;
                parts.remove(h+1);
                parts.set(h-1, String.valueOf(tempPROD));
                parts.remove(h);
                types.remove(h+1);
                types.set(h-1, "num");
                types.remove(h);
            }
            else if(parts.get(h).equals("/"))
            {
                tempPROD=tempP1/tempP2;
                parts.remove(h+1);
                parts.set(h-1, String.valueOf(tempPROD));
                parts.remove(h);
                types.remove(h+1);
                types.set(h-1, "num");
                types.remove(h);
            }
        //end of if operator conditional
        }
        else if((h!=parts.size()-1)&&((types.get(h).equals("num"))&&types.get(h+1).equals("num")))
        {
            tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h));
            tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
            tempPROD=tempP1*tempP2;
            parts.remove(h+1);
            parts.set(h, String.valueOf(tempPROD));
            types.remove(h+1);
            types.set(h, "num");
        }
    //end loop to go through each part of arraylist
    }
//end of method
}
```

Note that "parts" is an Arraylist of single-index String values, and "types" is the Arraylist of each of "parts"'s mathematical value.

This is the first programming question I have posted here, so I hope that I have provided enough information.

Comment: Looks like you need to debug your code. That's something you should do, not us, and if you don't know how, yet, now is a great time to learn. See: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: Thank you @Andreas I will try this and see if I can solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.  Basically, the error was reached when trying to evaluate a value `-Infinity3` because the loop continually tried to evaluate the function but the ArrayLists were not changed in two ways:

Firstly, the values that had been evaluated in the function were not removed properly.  Secondly, the ArrayLists themselves did not get cleared in each new instance of the `.evaluate()` method, in which `operateMD` was called.

I solved the problem by restructuring the method `operateMD` as follows:

```
public static void operateMD()
{
    //setTypes();
    double tempPROD=0;
    double tempP1=0;
    double tempP2=0;

    for(int h=0;h<parts.size();h++)
    {
        if(types.get(h).equals("opr")&&((types.get(h-1).equals("num"))&&types.get(h+1).equals("num")))
        {
            if(parts.get(h).equals("*"))
            {
                tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h-1));
                tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
                tempPROD=tempP1*tempP2;
                parts.set(h-1, String.valueOf(tempPROD));
                types.set(h-1, "num");
                parts.remove(h);
                parts.remove(h);
                types.remove(h);
                types.remove(h);
            }
            else if(parts.get(h).equals("/"))
            {
                tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h-1));
                tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
                tempPROD=tempP1/tempP2;
                parts.set(h-1, String.valueOf(tempPROD));
                types.set(h-1, "num");
                parts.remove(h);
                parts.remove(h);
                types.remove(h);
                types.remove(h);
            }
        //end of if operator conditional
        }
        else if((h!=parts.size()-1)&&((types.get(h).equals("num"))&&types.get(h+1).equals("num")))
        {   
            tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h));
            tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
            tempPROD=tempP1*tempP2;
            parts.set(h, String.valueOf(tempPROD));
            parts.remove(h+1);
            types.remove(h+1);
        }
    //end loop to go through each part of arraylist
    }
//end of method
}
```

and I added this method to be run before `operateMD()` was called by the loop:

```
public static void clear()
{
    for(int z=0;z<parts.size();z++)
    {
        parts.remove(z);
        types.remove(z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be one of the following lines:

```
tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h-1));
tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
...
tempP1=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h));
tempP2=Double.parseDouble(parts.get(h+1));
```

Looks like `parts` arraylist contains some non numeric values which your code tries to convert into `double` and hence, throws an `Exception`.

You can check if a string is numeric with `regex` before converting it into `double` e.g.:

```
if (parts.get(h-1).matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
//convert
}
```